# How to run the changed code without saving in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

If  I don't save the code, I can't run the changed code.It only output the previous result. Sometimes,The changed code could be worse or better,I'm not sure. So before run it,I don't want save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to save the code to run it.

However, you can always see the state of your file before your changes. In fact you can see the state of your file many changes back.

Please use Right Click => Team => Show Local History to access previous versions of the file. You can also revert to previous versions and compare current version to previous versions using "Replace With" and "Compare With" context menu items.

Also, consider using version control software such as subversion or git.

Comment: 'Local History' is in the 'Replace With' menu not 'Team'

Comment: @greg-449 It's in at least 3 places :) "Replace With", "Compare With" and "Team". Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. In any case, you (or eclipse) needs to save the changes in some file, so that it can be processed by the compiler.

Comment: Your answer looks like a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need more reputation in order to comment. Somehow you have to get started...

Answer (score 0):

You can go here and check the box Save automatically before build...

Windows > Preferences > General -> Workspace

you wrote "So before run it,I don't want save it" - actually what you want?