# Eclispe stops to run changed code without saving

Tags: java, eclipse

Something has happened with my Eclipse "Build automatically" function. It works recently: when I did some little edit (in *.java, *.xml etc. files) and pressed a "Run" or "Debug" button without saving (editor was "dirty") - my project started running with changes.

I haven't caught when exactly it has been broken, but now I have to press Ctrl+S after every added semicolon to look how it  has caught up on my code. It irritates very much. I tried to make eclipse -clean and uncheck-check box

*Window-Preferences-General-Workspace-Build-Build automatically*.

Nothing has changed.

It doesn't depend on the kind of a project (Maven or basic Java)

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Build id: 20220310-1457

Here [how-to-run-the-changed-code-without-saving-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352610/how-to-run-the-changed-code-without-saving-in-eclipse) I haven't found an answer.
Does anybody know how it works?

Comment: As the answers to the linked question say, such a feature never existed.

Comment: Look at the "save required editors before launching" option in "Run/Debug > Launching" in the preferences.

Comment: @Holger yes, it seems true but as I mentioned it have worked before.

Comment: @greg-449 Got it! Thank you, it works! If I'll not find anymore else - it'll a good aproach for sure. But it worked without saving I am not sleeping and used this...I guess... I'm starting doubt already.